# AJAX refresh div content without refresh page reloading in Cakephp , How to use here ajax for automatic reloading data content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp-2.3

In devicesController, I am using cakephp2.7

```
<?php
class DevicesController extends AppController {
public function index() {
$devices = $this->Device->find('all');
$mymoo=$this->set('mymoo', $this->Device->find('all'));
}
}
?>
```

In Device/index.ctp ,My data already stored database ,

```
<html>
<body>
<?php foreach ($mymoo as $value): ?>
<div class="iotsensors"> 
<div class="container">
<p> <?php echo $value['Device']['mac_address']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($value); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing your question to ask !

Comment: No , above , just for every time reloading page code , It runs fine , but when I reload page , I can see new data , I want to see new data without  page reloading , if possible help me , I know it is implemented by using ajax , but I don't know how to implement it , I am trying by myself unfortunately , it became unsuccessful